# jQuery .submit() not working with javascript-generated html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am having a bear of a time figuring out why a jQuery .submit() is not recognizing the submit.

The HTML form (actually multiple forms) are successfully generated into a div that is appended to the page with the following javascript function (this is called out of $(document).ready(function(){}):

```
function makeMenu(chambers,bins,values) {
    var htmlString = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < chambers.length; i++) {
        if(bins[i]) {
            var link = chambers[i] + " - " + bins[i];
            var p = values[i];
        }

        htmlString += "<form name='entity' id='entity' method='post' action=''>";
        htmlString += "<input type='submit' name='get_entity' id='to_php' value='" + link + "' class='text_button' title='value=" + p + "'>";
        htmlString += "<input type='hidden' name='tool' value='" + chambers[i] + "'/>";
        htmlString += "<input type = 'hidden' name='bin' value='" + bins[i] + "'/>";
        htmlString += "</form>";
    }

    $("#spacer").append("<div class='menu'>" + htmlString + "</div>");
}
```

Upon submitting a form I am just trying to get an alert to post to show that the submit is recognized but it does not get there:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#entity').submit(function() {
        alert('Success!');
    });
 })
```

I have tried making sure that the submit button did not have submit as the name and id and tried just generating a single form but no luck.  Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: When `$('#entity').submit()` is executed, do you think `$('#entity')` exists?

Comment: Also, element `id`s must be unique. Use a class instead.

Comment: I've run into another problem.  The makeMenu is creating multiple forms of class=entity.  When one of them is clicked on I want to pass the chamber and bin information to php using serialize.  Unfortunately, the serialized string contains the information for ALL chamber/bin combinations.  I need it to only include information for the link clicked.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit','#entity',function() {
        alert('Success!');
    });
 })
```

Comment: Responding to Alexandre as he had the first solution. Works great now.  I'm only a couple months into javascript/jquery, learn something new every day.  Also, per Jason I did change it to a class instead of id but it worked both ways.  Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: I've run into another problem. The makeMenu is creating multiple forms of class=entity. When one of them is clicked on I want to pass the chamber and bin information to php using serialize. Unfortunately, the serialized string contains the information for ALL chamber/bin combinations. I need it to only include information for the link clicked. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You are using jquery .serialize() ?

Comment: Yes. My ajax is per below

Comment: $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data: $('.entity').serialize(),
            url: 'get_prob.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Success');
            }
        });

Comment: Sorry for the delay. If you have multiple forms and want to serialize specifically one, use: $(this).serialize(); inside on function ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of submit. As the form is created by jQuery it isn't bound to the document yet.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit','#entity',function() {
        alert("success");
    });
 })
```